# Django Template not rendering from database

Tags: django, django-templates, django-class-based-views

I am using *Class Based Views* and so far it's going good. 
Recently I came across something logical or code related, which I'm unable to understand.

I have an html file, where I want to pass or display my two models:
`PhotographyData` and `Pictures`. I am successfully able to pass the models through using two different `ListView`. But the Pictures ListView is not showing any data but it's showing me the object id.

Similarly I tried creating a `PicturesDetailView` to check if the database isn't causing any error, and even in that DetailView there isn't any data or any id getting passed.

views.py

```py
class PhotographyListView(ListView):
    model = PhotographyData
    template_name = "projectfiles/PhotographyView.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return PhotographyData.objects.all()


class PicturesListView(ListView):
    model = Pictures
    template_name = "projectfiles/PhotographyView.html"
    queryset = Pictures.objects.all()


class PicturesDetail(DetailView):
    model = Pictures
    template_name = 'projectfiles/View.html'
```

models.py

```py
class PhotographyData(models.Model):
    photography_pkg_name = models.CharField(
        "Photography package", max_length=50)
    photography_pic = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='images', blank=False, null=False)
    photography_price = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)


class Pictures(models.Model):
    pic_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pic_caption = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'Pictures', blank=False, null=False)
```

forms.py

```py
class PhotographyForm(forms.ModelForm):

#overriding the required attribute
    photography_pic = forms.ImageField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = PhotographyData
        fields = ("photography_pkg_name",
                  "photography_price", "photography_pic")


class PicturesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # date = forms.DateField(
    #     widget=forms.DateInput(format=('%m/%d/%y'),
    #                            attrs={'class': 'form-control',
    #                                   'placeholder': ' Month/Date/Year'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Pictures
        fields = ("pic_name", "pic_caption",
                  "date", "location", "pic")

    widgets = {
        # 'date': forms.DateTimeField(
        #     attrs={'placeholder': "Month/Date/Year:H:M" }
        #     ),

        'pic_caption': forms.Textarea(
            attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Caption', 'rows': 3, 'cols': 21})}

    pic = forms.ImageField(required = True)

#'%m/%d/%Y % H: % M'
```

urls.py

```py
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.views.generic import *
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

from .views import (
    HomeView,
    Food_CreateView,
    Decor_CreateView,
    Photography_CreateView,
    FoodListView,
    DecorListView,
    PhotographyListView,
    PicturesCreateView,
    PicturesDetail)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?i)home/$', HomeView.as_view(), name='Home-Page'),
    url(r'^(?i)addpic/$', Photography_CreateView.as_view(), name='Add-Pic'),
    url(r'^(?i)addabc/$', PicturesCreateView.as_view(), name='Add-Pic'),
    url(r'^(?i)PhotoView/$', PhotographyListView.as_view(), name='Photo-View'),
    url(r'^(?i)(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', PicturesDetail.as_view(), name='Pic-View'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

## DetailView for Pictures

View.html

```
<title>123</title>
{% include 'projectfiles/base.html' %}

ABC
<div class='collection'>
{% for x in object_list %}
<br>
ID:{{x.id}}<br>
NAME:{{x.pic_name}}<br>
DATE:{{x.date}}<br>
Location:{{x.location}}
Details:{{x.pic_caption}}

<img src="{{ i.pic.url }}" alt='Not found' width="124" height="124"/>
{% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock asd %}
```

photography.html

```
<title>VIEW</title>
{% include 'projectfiles/base.html' %}

{% block asd %}


<div class='collection'>
{% for i in object_list %}

{{i.photography_pkg_name}}
{{i.photography_price}}
<a href=#> <img src="{{ i.photography_pic.url }}" alt='Not found' width="124" height="124"/></a>
{% endfor %}
</div>
<br>
<div class='collection'>

{% for x in object_list %}
ABC<br>
ID:{{x.id}}<br>
{% comment %} ID:<a href={% url 'Pic-View' x.id %}>{{x.id}}</a><br> {% endcomment %}
NAME:{{x.pic_name}}<br>
DATE:{{x.date}}<br>
Location:{{x.location}}
{% endfor %}
</div>


{% endcomment %}

{% endblock asd %}
```

I am using **Django forms** to save data in the db and it's working.

There are no errors which makes it confusing to understand why is the data not passing properly. Though it is successfully saved and shown in the admin section.

[image: Problem]

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. Apart from anything else, you don't seem to have a URL for the PicturesListView. What, *exactly*, are you seeing, on what URL, and how is that different from what you expect?

Comment: (Also, probably not related, but that isn't at all how you use template inheritance. Please go back and read the [template inheritance docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance).)

Comment: The URL is just passing data to render for display. I'll show you a visual representation if that helps.

Comment: But that didn't answer my question. Which URL are you actually using, to show the problem? And why isn't there one for PicturesListView?

Comment: **url(r'^(?i)PhotoView/$', PhotographyListView.as_view(), name='Photo-View'),**

 is for listview

    **url(r'^(?i)(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', PicturesDetail.as_view(), name='Pic-View')**  

 for the Picture model item details

Comment: `object_list` contains Photography items, not Pictures. It cannot be both at the same time.

Comment: @IvanStarostin Yes I've tried  **context_object_name = "Pics"** and there's no data coming through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all a bit confused. You have one template and one URL, but you seem to be expecting two views to somehow be invoked. That's not at all how it works: one URL maps to one view. Multiple views can of course use the same template, but not at the same time.

Because your URL calls PhotographyListView, `object_list` is only ever going to contain instances of PhotographyData. If you want to also show a list of Pictures, you need to add that into the view context:

```
class PhotographyListView(ListView):
    model = PhotographyData
    template_name = "projectfiles/PhotographyView.html"


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['pictures'] = Pictures.objects.all()
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

and now in the template the second loop can be `{% for x in pictures %}`.

(Although, again, I can't really understand why you want these two separate lists. Perhaps you want some kind of relationship between Picture and PhotographyData? If so you need a ForeignKey for example.)

Comment: The idea is that the top portion of the page will display the packages of the photography and the rest of the page will display the pictures by the photographer. As you say that object_list will only work for PhotographyData, I agree and have tried it. But i'm using a different view as you can see in the Views.py to render the pictures inside the Pictures model with the **context_object_name = "Pics"** even then I'm unable to see the data. and whats weird is that the data isn't showing up in the DetailView either. Hopefully you understood what I'm trying to achieve here.

Comment: I have given you the answer. You cannot call two views at the same time. Setting a random attribute will not do anything at all, because *that view is not being called*. And like I also said, if you want to relate pictures to a specific photographer then you need an actual relationship in the models.

Comment: Separately of course, the detail view does not work because you have a loop through object_list; a detail view does not have a list, it references a single instance.

Comment: That solves the Detail view issue. Can you suggest an alternative solution to my ListView issue.

Comment: I have given you the answer, including code. Why do you need an alternative?

Comment: Got it. I understand it now. Thanks a lot.